# A sufficient condition for infinite horizon optimal control problems

Tags: reference-request, optimal-control

Consider the following problem:
\begin{align}
&\max_{u(\cdot)}\int_0^\infty{e^{-rt}F(x(t),u(t))dt}\\
\mathrm{s.t.}&\quad \dot x(t) = f(x(t),u(t)), x(0)= x_0.
\end{align}
Let $H = F + \lambda f$ denote the Hamiltonian.
Pontryagin's maximum principle provides necessary optimality conditions
\begin{align}
&0 = \frac{\partial H}{\partial u},\\[2mm]
&\dot \lambda = r \lambda - \frac{\partial H}{\partial x},\\[2mm]
&\lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-rt}\lambda(t)x(t) = 0.
\end{align}
For sufficiency one usually requires that $H$ is concave in $(x,u)$ [Mangasarian] or that the maximized Hamiltonian is concave in $x$ [Arrow].
I read, however, the following sentence in a paper ([pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj_i6vf46zsAhVJCewKHRyzC-QQFjAAegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.539.6143%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&usg=AOvVaw1cmRFIDhOTTMYzt-ngsR4v)):

> In fact sufficiency is satisfied for trajectories converging to the locally stable steady states of the cooperative solution and open-loop equilibria.

I've never seen this and was wondering whether there exists a formal proof for this claim.